# How can I view data from multiple pages in the same DataGridView by c #?

Tags: c#

I can display data from a single sheet using the following code.But I want to display data from multiple sheet in the same datagridview.Could you please help me?
Thank you in advance.

```
    OleDbConnection xlsxbaglanti = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + @"Data Source=;" + @"Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;Mode=Read;ReadOnly=True';");
    DataTable tablo = new DataTable();

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            xlsxbaglanti.Open();
            tablo.Clear();
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Sheet2$]", xlsxbaglanti);
            da.Fill(tablo);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = tablo;
            xlsxbaglanti.Close();



        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Programda Hata Meydana Geldi." + Environment.NewLine + "Hata : " + ex.Message, "Hata", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Don't clear the table.  The adapter will append new data in the same table.

Comment: add `JOIN [AnotherSheet$]` to your `SELECT * FROM [Sheet2$]`

Comment: Sheet count is changing.So new pages are added and I do not want to add them every time.I am looking for a dynamic solution.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sheet names can be retrieved `GetOleDbSchemaTable`method of `OleDbConnection` class.

For more details, please refer [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8096/C-Retrieve-Excel-Workbook-Sheet-Names) code project article.

After retrieving the table names, the select statement can be built dynamically.

Hope this helps.